# Mock Location using FusedLocation

Tags: java, android, textview, google-api, location

My question is I've got my method for mock location setup to an onclick button, however, I've got a location that is stored in a variable called lbldummylocation. both latitude and longitude coordinates are in one textview.

When I click my button setPhoneLocation (the method of the same name) 
is invoked and the location stored in that textview(lbldummylocation) becomes my phone's location!

My Location Manager points Null and can't set textview in lat/long? I am using GoogleMPIClient and FusedLocation. please help! any ideas?

Class:

```
  /**
     * Everything for Location Requests
     * */

    private final static int PLAY_SERVICES_RESOLUTION_REQUEST = 1000; //1 sec

    private Location mLastLocation;

    // Google client to interact with Google API
    private GoogleApiClient mGoogleApiClient;

    // boolean flag to toggle periodic location updates
    private boolean mRequestingLocationUpdates = false;

    private LocationRequest mLocationRequest;
    private LocationManager mLocationManager;

    // Location updates intervals in sec
    private static int UPDATE_INTERVAL = 10000; // 10 sec
    private static int FATEST_INTERVAL = 5000; // 5 sec
    private static int DISPLACEMENT = 10; // 10 meters

    /**
     * Fields
     * */
    // UI elements
    private TextView lblLocation, lblLocation2, lblLocation3, lblDummyLocation;
    private Button btnShowLocation, btnStartLocationUpdates, btnAddLocation, btnViewPhoneLocation, btnViewAllPhoneLocation, btnSetPhoneLocation, btnStartLocationService, btnStopLocationService;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_user_location);


            lblDummyLocation = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.lblDummyLocation);

            btnSetPhoneLocation = (Button) findViewById(R.id.btnSetPhoneLocation);


        // First we need to check availability of play services
        if (checkPlayServices()) {

            // Building the GoogleApi client
            buildGoogleApiClient();

            createLocationRequest();


        }


        //Get location button click listener
        btnSetPhoneLocation.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                setMockLocation();
            }
        });

    }

       private void setMockLocation() {
  mLocationManager.removeTestProvider(LocationManager.GPS_PROVIDER);
  mLocationManager.addTestProvider
            (
            LocationManager.GPS_PROVIDER,
            "requiresNetwork" == "",
            "requiresSatellite" == "",
            "requiresCell" == "",
            "hasMonetaryCost" == "",
            "supportsAltitude" == "",
            "supportsSpeed" == "",
            "supportsBearing" == "",

            android.location.Criteria.POWER_LOW,
            android.location.Criteria.ACCURACY_FINE
            );

    Location newLocation = new Location(LocationManager.GPS_PROVIDER);

    newLocation.setLatitude (lblDummyLocation);
    newLocation.setLongitude(lblDummyLocation);

    newLocation.setAccuracy(500);

    mLocationManager.setTestProviderEnabled
            (
                    LocationManager.GPS_PROVIDER,
                    true
            );

    mLocationManager.setTestProviderStatus
            (
                    LocationManager.GPS_PROVIDER,
                    LocationProvider.AVAILABLE,
                    null,
                    System.currentTimeMillis()
            );

    mLocationManager.setTestProviderLocation
            (
                    LocationManager.GPS_PROVIDER,
                    newLocation
            );
}

    @Override
    protected void onStart() {
        super.onStart();
        if (mGoogleApiClient != null) {
            mGoogleApiClient.connect();
        }
    }

    @Override
    protected void onResume() {
        super.onResume();

        checkPlayServices();

        // Resuming the periodic location updates
        if (mGoogleApiClient.isConnected() && mRequestingLocationUpdates) {
            startLocationUpdates();
        }
    }

    @Override
    protected void onStop() {
        super.onStop();
        if (mGoogleApiClient.isConnected()) {
            mGoogleApiClient.disconnect();
        }
    }

    @Override
    protected void onPause() {
        super.onPause();
        stopLocationUpdates();
    }

    /**
     * Method to display the location on UI
     * */
    private void displayLocation() {

        mLastLocation = LocationServices.FusedLocationApi
                .getLastLocation(mGoogleApiClient);

        if (mLastLocation != null) {
            double latitude = mLastLocation.getLatitude();
            double longitude = mLastLocation.getLongitude();

            lblLocation.setText(latitude + ", " + longitude);
            lblLocation2.setText("" + latitude);
            lblLocation3.setText("" + longitude);


        } else {

            lblLocation
                    .setText("(Couldn't get the location. Make sure location is enabled on the device)");
        }
    }

    /**
     * Method to toggle periodic location updates
     * */
    private void togglePeriodicLocationUpdates() {
        if (!mRequestingLocationUpdates) {
            // Changing the button text
            btnStartLocationUpdates
                    .setText(getString(R.string.btn_stop_location_updates));

            mRequestingLocationUpdates = true;

            // Starting the location updates
            startLocationUpdates();

            Log.d(TAG, "Periodic location updates started!");

        } else {
            // Changing the button text
            btnStartLocationUpdates
                    .setText(getString(R.string.btn_start_location_updates));

            mRequestingLocationUpdates = false;

            // Stopping the location updates
            stopLocationUpdates();

            Log.d(TAG, "Periodic location updates stopped!");
        }
    }

    /**
     * Creating google api client object
     * */
    protected synchronized void buildGoogleApiClient() {
        mGoogleApiClient = new GoogleApiClient.Builder(this)
                .addConnectionCallbacks(this)
                .addOnConnectionFailedListener(this)
                .addApi(LocationServices.API).build();
    }

    /**
     * Creating location request object
     * */
    protected void createLocationRequest() {
        mLocationRequest = new LocationRequest();
        mLocationRequest.setInterval(UPDATE_INTERVAL);
        mLocationRequest.setFastestInterval(FATEST_INTERVAL);
        mLocationRequest.setPriority(LocationRequest.PRIORITY_HIGH_ACCURACY);
        mLocationRequest.setSmallestDisplacement(DISPLACEMENT);
    }

    /**
     * Method to verify google play services on the device
     * */
    private boolean checkPlayServices() {
        int resultCode = GooglePlayServicesUtil
                .isGooglePlayServicesAvailable(this);
        if (resultCode != ConnectionResult.SUCCESS) {
            if (GooglePlayServicesUtil.isUserRecoverableError(resultCode)) {
                GooglePlayServicesUtil.getErrorDialog(resultCode, this,
                        PLAY_SERVICES_RESOLUTION_REQUEST).show();
            } else {
                Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),
                        "This device is not supported.", Toast.LENGTH_LONG)
                        .show();
                finish();
            }
            return false;
        }
        return true;
    }

    /**
     * Starting the location updates
     * */
    protected void startLocationUpdates() {

        LocationServices.FusedLocationApi.requestLocationUpdates(
                mGoogleApiClient, mLocationRequest, this);

    }

    /**
     * Stopping location updates
     */
    protected void stopLocationUpdates() {
        LocationServices.FusedLocationApi.removeLocationUpdates(
                mGoogleApiClient, this);
    }

    /**
     * Google api callback methods
     */
    @Override
    public void onConnectionFailed(ConnectionResult result) {
        Log.i(TAG, "Connection failed: ConnectionResult.getErrorCode() = "
                + result.getErrorCode());
    }

    @Override
    public void onConnected(Bundle arg0) {

        // Once connected with google api, get the location
        displayLocation();

        if (mRequestingLocationUpdates) {
            startLocationUpdates();
        }
    }

    @Override
    public void onConnectionSuspended(int arg0) {
        mGoogleApiClient.connect();
    }

    @Override
    public void onLocationChanged(Location location) {
        // Assign the new location
        mLastLocation = location;

        Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Location changed!",
                Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

        // Displaying the new location on UI
        displayLocation();
    }
```

Comment: did you add permission for mock location ? and enabled mock location in developer settings ?

Comment: @MurtazaKhursheedHussain...Yes, I just need help with the method on how to set it up to take my textview location and set it for the phone. any ideas?

Comment: your set    private void setMockLocation() {

    } is empty

Comment: @MurtazaKhursheedHussain...Yes, I need help for that part, how do I take set it up with for Mock Locations using my textview?

Comment: @MurtazaKhursheedHussain...See edits, I found a tutorial and am working with it, I am getting a null pointed even with set coordinates and I can't set my textview to the lat/long? any ideas?